# Matlab Object Oriented Programming: Setting and getting properties for multiple objects

Tags: oop, class, matlab, get, set

I have a class like so:

```
classdef Vehicle < handle
    %Vehicle
    %   Vehicle superclass

    properties
        Is_Active  % Does the vehicle exist in the simualtion world?
        Speed      % [Km/Hour]
    end

    methods
        function this = Vehicle(varargin)
            this.Speed = varargin{1}; % The speed of the car
            this.Is_Active = true;
        end
    end
end
```

I create my Vehicle-class objects in a cell form (don't ask me why - it's a laymen's workaround for global setting):

```
Vehicles{1} = Vehicle(100);
Vehicles{2} = Vehicle(200);
Vehicles{3} = Vehicle(50);
Vehicles{1}.Is_Active = true;
Vehicles{2}.Is_Active = true;
Vehicles{3}.Is_Active = true;
```

My questions:
1. Is there a way to set all three objects' active in a single command?
2. Is there a way to get all three objects' Speed in a single command?
3. Is there a way to query which vehicles are faster than X in a single command?

Thanks
Gabriel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the members of the same class you can use round brackets (regular array):

```
Vehicles(1) = Vehicle(100);
Vehicles(2) = Vehicle(200);
Vehicles(3) = Vehicle(50);
```

To set all objects use [`deal`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/deal.html):

```
[Vehicles(:).Is_Active] = deal( true );
```

You could also [initialize an array of objects](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/creating-object-arrays.html) in the first place.

For your questions (2) and (3) the syntax is equivalent to those of MATLAB structures:

```
speedArray = [Vehicles.Speed];
fasterThanX = Vehicles( speedArray > X );
```

Such vectorization notation is a [strong point of MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1100/1109.html) and is used extensively.